# Label not lining up to right of radio button

Tags: jquery, html, element

I am building a list of jquery options to select using radio buttons and labels, I have embedded the radio buttons and labels in a bootstrap panel, but the radios buttons and labels are not matching up, actually the label is below the radio button for each option.

[image]

```
function renderShippingMethods(element) {
var $ele = $(element);
var radios = ShippingMethods.map(function(sm) {
    var label = $("<label>").text(sm.ShippingName + " $" + sm.Price),
        input = $("<input>")
            .attr({
                type: "radio",
                name: "ShippingMethod",
                value: sm.ShippingMethodId
            });
        //span = $("<span>").addClass("radio-option");
    return label.prepend(input);
});
$ele.append(radios);
}
```

And here is the html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Shipping Methods</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="shippingMethod"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your CSS?

Comment: By default, `input` and `label` are both inline elements. The HTML and JS you've added to your question are not responsible for the block-level behaviour you're experiencing.

Comment: So I really don't have a css stylr that it is using, so should I create some css to get it to line up correctly?

Comment: Do something like this: HTML: `<div>
  <input type="radio" />
  <label>Standard</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" />
  <label>Two-day</label>
</div>
` and CSS `input,
label {
  display: inline-block;
}
`

Comment: Thanks guys figured it out